# select * in table_a left join table_b when certain_field is null in table_b

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

table_a contains all orders, while table_b contains only special orders. Every order in each table has a code_field. All orders in table_b are also in table_a, but of course not all orders in table_a are also in table_b. I need to extract all orders in table_a that are not also in table_b. Looking for a solution but I actually cannot figure out how to write it.

Comment: Please share the table structures, sample input data, the expected output data, and your current attempts - this helps others to understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select everything from `table_a` and left join `table_b` by `code_field` and wherever you don't have matching order in `table_b` the fields will be null

```
SELECT table_a.*
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
  ON table_a.code_field = table_b.code_field
  AND table_b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: what is "id" of "table_b.id"? Maybe the row id?

Comment: @gab just a non-null field from `table_b`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table_b
  WHERE table_a.code_field = table_b.code_field
)
```